# Insert into a table data from same table

Tags: sql

I have a table that I need to update that is basically duplicate data except for the one column of data.

My table name is `tblSupporters`

My columns are

```
ID, SYear, Type, Support Location, City, State, Info.
```

I need to copy the data from my table where `SYear` equals 2012 and insert into the same table but change the `SYear` to 2013.

I know this is simple, but I'm so new to this.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into tblSupporters(ID, SYear, Type, Support Location, City, State, Info)
    select ID, 2013 as SYear, Type, Support Location, City, State, Info
    from tblSupporters
    where SYear = 2012;
```

My guess is that the `id` is automatically assigned, so you might really want:

```
insert into tblSupporters(SYear, Type, Support Location, City, State, Info)
    select 2013 as SYear, Type, Support Location, City, State, Info
    from tblSupporters
    where SYear = 2012;
```